# C# movement script not taking effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script that I have for movement in 3d space is not applying to the object. I'm a beginner so i'm assuming there's something i need to add to the script to make it work. I used a script i seen in a video but i did replace their use of Rigidbody2d to Rigidbody in order to suit my needs.

I was expecting the component of rigidbody to be able to move left and right but it had no effect on the object. If you know why, please help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    private Rigidbody body3d;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        body3d = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var val = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        body3d.velocity = new Vector3(speed * val, body3d.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you pressing the arrow keys?  Have you added debug prints to make sure `val` is getting set to -1 or 1?

Comment: Found the Solution. I should have been using FixedUpdate instead of just Update

Comment: Using FixedUpdate() may sometimes miss your key presses. The correct way is to have the input cached in Update() and in FixedUpdate() to influence the velocity based on that cached input values. The reason you are not noticing the problem is because you are getting an axis and not a key press/release.